# PHP Scripts not working with Plesk

Tags: php, mysqli, settings, plesk

It's the first time that I've worked with Plesk. Before using Plesk, this website and scripts were all fully functional all of the PHP was working without issue although once it was moved to a different host using Plesk, most of the PHP is now showing up as plain text. Some of the includes are working, but a lot of the short MySQLi commands do not work, such as;

```
$conn->query
$result2->fetch_row()
$result->num_rows
```

Also, when I try and perform a very simple test, such as;

```
$test = 'hello';
echo $test;
```

I get nothing returning? Here is an example of one of the scripts I am using and how it shows up on the website...

```
<?
if($show == 'All'){
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `xWKaiNXU_news` WHERE `news_public` = '1' ORDER BY `news_date` DESC LIMIT 100");
        } else {
        if($show == 'EVENT'){
                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `xWKaiNXU_news` WHERE (`news_type` = 'EVENT' OR `news_type` = 'PDF') AND `news_public` = '1' ORDER BY `news_date` DESC LIMIT 100");   
            } else {
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `xWKaiNXU_news` WHERE `news_type` = '$show' AND `news_public` = '1' ORDER BY `news_date` DESC LIMIT 100");    
            }
        }
          $result = $sql;
echo $test;
          if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $news_id = $row['news_id'];
                    $news_type = $row['news_type'];
                    $news_title = $row['news_title'];
                    $news_tagline = $row['news_tagline'];
                    $news_date = date('dS F Y', strtotime($row['news_date']));
                    $news_time = date('H:i', strtotime($row['news_date']));
                    $news_image = $row['news_image'];


                    if($news_type == 'PDF'){
                        $news_text = $row['news_text'];
                    ?>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                      <article class="post">
                        <div class="row" align="center">


                    <?
                    if($news_tagline == 'port'){
                    ?>
                    <hr>
                    <p>From: <h4><? echo $news_date; ?></h4></p>
                    <p><? echo $news_text; ?></p>
                     <object data="<? echo $news_image; ?>" type="application/pdf" width="80%" height="600px">
  <p>Alternative link - <a href="<? echo $news_image; ?>">PDF Viewer</a></p>
</object>

                    <?  
                    } else {
                    ?>
                    <hr>
                    <p>From: <h4><? echo $news_date; ?></h4></p>
                    <p><? echo $news_text; ?></p>
                     <object data="<? echo $news_image; ?>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="550px">
  <p>Alternative link - <a href="<? echo $news_image; ?>">PDF Viewer</a></p>
</object>
                    <?  
                    }
                    ?>




                    </div>
                    </article>
                    </div>  
                    <?  

                    } else {
                        if($news_image == ''){
                        $news_dp_image = 'assets/images/default.jpg';
                    } else {
                        $news_dp_image = 'news_images/'.$news_image;
                    }
                    ?>



                    <!-- ======================= ARTICLE #4 ======================-->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <article class="post">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-2">
                            <figure class="stretchy-wrapper ratio_1-1"><a href="full_news.php?id=<? echo $news_id; ?>" title="Post" style="background-image: url('<? echo $news_dp_image; ?>'); box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 5px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.35);"></a></figure>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                            <h3 class="post_title"><a href="full_news.php?id=<? echo $news_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b><? echo $news_title; ?></b></a></h3>
                            <p><? echo $news_tagline; ?></p>
                            <div class="post_figure_and_info">
                              <div class="post_sub"><span class="post_info post_date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <? echo $news_date; ?> </span><a href="#"><span class="post_info post_author">at <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b><? echo $news_time; ?></b></span></a><a href="#"><span class="post_info post_categories"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b><? echo $news_type; ?></b></span></a></div>
                            </div>
                            <p><a href="full_news.php?id=<? echo $news_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Read More</a></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </article>
                    </div>

                    <?
                    }
              }
          } else {
              ?>


              <hr>

              <?
          }
              ?>
```

How it displays:

0) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $news_id = $row['news_id']; $news_type = $row['news_type']; $news_title = $row['news_title']; $news_tagline = $row['news_tagline']; $news_date = date('dS F Y', strtotime($row['news_date'])); $news_time = date('H:i', strtotime($row['news_date'])); $news_image = $row['news_image']; if($news_type == 'PDF'){ $news_text = $row['news_text']; ?>
From:

From:

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? I've tried different PHP versions and such but I don't get many options...

```
Performance settings
memory_limit 
128M (Default)
max_execution_time 
30 (Default)
max_input_time 
60 (Default)
post_max_size 
8M (Default)
upload_max_filesize 
2M (Default)
opcache.enable 
on (Default)
Common settings
include_path 
.:/usr/share/php (Default)
session.save_path 
/var/lib/php/sessions (Default)
mail.force_extra_parameters 
open_basedir 
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}
error_reporting 
E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors 
off (Default)
log_errors 
on (Default)
allow_url_fopen 
on (Default)
file_uploads 
on (Default)
short_open_tag 
off (Default)
```

Comment: Maybe the short open tags (`<?`) are an issue, I've seen it several times that they have been disabled in the interpreter. Try changing them to `<?php`.

Comment: @TobiasK That solved it... How annoying, always the last thing to consider. If you could add this as an answer, I will mark it as correct! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122483/php-scripts-not-working-with-plesk?noredirect=1#comment89231110_51122483), the issue was that short open tags (`<?`) were disabled / not interpreted. Changing them to `<?php` solved the issue.